# Can Hash Length Extension attacks be avoided by changing the data structure?

Tags: cryptography, hash

I read about Hash Length Extension attacks [here](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Modern+Web+Application+Penetration+Testing+Hash+Length+Extension+Attacks/22792/) and [here](https://blog.skullsecurity.org/2012/everything-you-need-to-know-about-hash-length-extension-attacks). From the articles I gained that this attack relies on the data structure, in the way that the secret has to be prefixed to the data (please correct me if I'm wrong). If that was the case, would it be a reasonable defense mechanism against this kind of attack to simply move the secret in the data structure?

From the [article](https://blog.skullsecurity.org/2012/everything-you-need-to-know-about-hash-length-extension-attacks):

```
let secret = "secret"
let data = "data"
let H = md5()
let signature = hash(secret || data)
```

Would this (i.e. moving the secret to the middle of the signature):

```
let signature = hash( string.Format( "{0}{1}{2}", data.Substring( 0, ( int ) ( data.Length / 2 ) ), secret, data.Substring( ( int ) ( data.Length / 2 ) ) ) );
```

be safe?

Comment: you can just swap the order of input to `data || secret` or use a sponge-based hash. `hash(secret || hash(secret || data))` would also work.

Comment: [This attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2717/991) still applies. ​ ​

Answer (score 2):

Let formalize the secret in the middle as;

```
signature = Hash( m[1..l/2] || secret || m[l/2+1..l] )
```

where `l = len(m)`. This construction is not differ from the original `H(k,m)` since simply consider that `k = m[1..l/2] || secret` and then apply the length extension attack, **success**!

The attack append-only attack `H(m,k)` - linked by user49075 on the comments - described in section 6 of the HMAC paper, "[Keying hash functions for message authentication"](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Emihir/papers/kmd5.pdf) by Bellare, Canetti, and Krawczyk only works if

1. The hash function is not collision-resistant, and
2. The collision pairs have the same length.

Of course, once the hash function is turned into non-collision resistant like MD5 and SHA-1, it might be easy to find files that have the same length.

The good point is that HMAC doesn't require the underlying hash function to be collision-resistant.

- [New Proofs for NMAC and HMAC: Security without Collision-Resistance](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Emihir/papers/hmac-new.pdf)

So you can use HMAC-SHA1 even though SHA-1 has lost its collision resistance.

The construction of the HMAC is complex due to the Merkle-Damgard construction. With the SHA-3, due to it's resistance to length extension attack, one can use [KMAC](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/specialpublications/nist.sp.800-185.pdf)

Similarly, one can use `Blake2(K||m)` safely since Blake2's design is based on the HAIFA constitution and that can be easily turned into length extension attack resistant hash function as in Blake2.

- [Why HAIFA and sponge constructions are not prone to length extension attacks?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83342/18298)